# is it safe to use ThreadPoolExecutor inside AsyncTask doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

I have to download a Json with a list of files, and then parallel download the files in the list. I would like to update periodically the `ProgressDialog`, so I implemented in this way

- I create and show the dialog
- I start an `AsyncTask`

  - `onProgressUpdate` receives 2 Integers, current progress and max progress, and updates the progress bar
  - `doInBackground`

    - downloads the json file and obtains the list of files to download
    - creates a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (tpe), with a `LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>`
    - submit a runnable for each file, that download the file to disk using Apache *commons-io `FileUtils.copyURLToFile`*
    - exec shutdown
  - in a while cycle. *tpe.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)* invokes periodically *publishProgress( (int) tpe.getCompletedTaskCount(), tot)*, to update the progress bar
  - onPostExecute hides and dismisses the progres bar, and manages the files downloades

is there any problem in using ThreadPoolExecutor inside an AsynTask? 
I am discussing with a colleague who claims that there could be problems in the threads management, that could deadlock, and that might give us problems on future versions

that's the code

```
public static void syncFiles(...)
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    sWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    sWakelock.acquire();

    sProgress = new ProgressDialog(context);
    sProgress.setCancelable(false);
    sProgress.setTitle("MyTitle");
    sProgress.setMessage("Sincronizzazione in corso");
    sProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    sProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
    sProgress.show();

    sCurrentTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Manifest>()
    {

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            if ((sProgress != null) && sProgress.isShowing())
                sProgress.dismiss();

            if ((sWakelock != null) && sWakelock.isHeld())
                sWakelock.release();
        };

        @Override
        protected Manifest doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            ArrayList files = getFiles(....)// download the jsonfile, and return the list of files

            final String baseurl = ... //  get the remote base url
            final String baselocal = ... //get the local base path ;

            int tot = m.size();

            publishProgress(0, tot);

            final int MAX_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); * 4;

            ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                            MAX_THREADS,
                            MAX_THREADS,
                            1,
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
                            );

            for (final String s: files)
            {

                tpe.submit(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            URL remoteUrl = new URL(baseurl + s);
                            File localUrl = new File(baselocal, s);
                            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(remoteUrl, localUrl, 60000, 60000);
                            Log.w(TAG, "Downloaded " + localUrl.getAbsolutePath() + " in " + remoteUrl);
                        } catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e(TAG, "download error " + e);
                            // error management logic
                        }
                    }

                });
            }

            tpe.shutdown();
            int num = 0;
            publishProgress(num, tot);
            try
            {
                while (!tpe.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                {
                    int n = (int) tpe.getCompletedTaskCount();
                    Log.w(TAG, "COUTN:  " + n + "/" + tot);
                    if (n != num)
                    {
                        num = n;
                        publishProgress(num, tot);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return m;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog)
        {
       if (sProgress.getMax() != prog[1])                {
                sProgress.setMax(prog[1]);
            }
            sProgress.setProgress(prog[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Manifest result)
        {

            sWakelock.release();
            sProgress.hide();
            sProgress.dismiss();

            // manage results
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: so what you did friend ? i also need to update progress during Thread Pool execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll checkout the implementation of AsyncTask then youi can find that AsyncTask itself has ThreadPool so it will start the task on separate thread. Acutually when we can the .execute() to start the background task this method is typically used with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR to allow multiple tasks to run in parallel on a pool of threads managed by AsyncTask. So why you need to implement another.

Update
Read about executeOnExecutor in [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) may be this can help you... It clearly says that if you are allowing multiple tasks to run in parallel from a thread pool is generally not what one wants, because the order of their operation is not defined....but here you want to download the files so I don't think the order is important so in my view you can use it and it'll not create any issue.

Comment: I need to exec the downloads in parallel. I'm downloading thousand of very small file, so I spend a lot of time in opening and closing communications and files.

Performance is really better downloading 4 or 8 files in parallel